# java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(byte[]) Returns Null

Tags: java, image, swing

Class `javax.swing.ImageIcon` has a constructor with a single `byte[]` parameter. Here is part of the code for that constructor:

```java
this.image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imageData);
if (image == null) {
    return;
}
```

Sometimes when I call this constructor, the `image` is indeed null and I can't discover why. Inspecting the source code for class `java.awt.Toolkit` shows that method `createImage(byte[])` calls abstract method `createImage(byte[], int, int)`. From my debugging, static method `getDefaultToolkit()` of class `java.awt.Toolkit` returns an instance of `sun.awt.windows.WToolkit` whose superclass is `sun.awt.SunToolkit` and that class contains an implementation for the method `createImage(byte[], int, int)`. I searched the Internet for the source code for method `createImage(byte[], int, int)` in class `sun.awt.SunToolkit` and found that it contains a single line:

```java
return createImage(new ByteArrayImageSource(data, offset, length));
```

Now comes the part where I may be missing something. Class `sun.awt.image.ByteArrayImageSource` extends class `sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource` and class `sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource` implements interface `sun.awt.image.ImageProducer`, so I think that method `createImage(new ByteArrayImageSource(data, offset, length)` refers to method `createImage(ImageProducer)` in class `SunToolkit`. I have looked at the source code for method `createImage(ImageProducer)` as well as the code for the `ByteArrayImageSource` constructor and I can't see why any of the `createImage()` methods would return null. By the way class `InputStreamImageSource` has no constructor.

So my question is: Why does `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(byte[])` **sometimes** return null?

Note that I cannot provide sample code to reproduce the problem becuase sometimes the same byte array will result in an image being created and sometimes it won't. Basically I am just invoking the `ImageIcon` constructor and passing it a byte array.

This is a *Swing* application and all the code is running on the event dispatch thread (EDT).

Comment: Is the method creating the image asynchronously? The docs do not state it is, but from memory a lot of the `Toolkit` methods involving image loading are. Try adding it to a [`MediaTracker`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/MediaTracker.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson how can I discover if calling `new ImageIcon(bytes)` is creating an image asynchronously? Regarding your suggestion: _Try adding it to a MediaTracker_ Can you point me to sample code showing how to achieve this?

Comment: *"I don't have an image"* Then what's `this.image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imageData);`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson my problem is that method `createImage()` is returning null. Please correct me if I'm wrong but if the method returns null, that means I don't have an image, doesn't it?